# Unable to run app on device, android

Tags: android, hardware

I am new to android and am trying to develop an app. 
I have a phone connected to my laptop and was testing on it this morning. 
But when I try to run the app on the phone now, the device shows up, but I am not able to click ok and start it. 
By the way, I am able to run the app on the emulator.
 
My manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.DuckTag"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".DuckTagActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application> </manifest>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you please try to rephrase yourself? First you're saying that you can't get your app to run, yet you end up adding that you're able to run the app. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of device are you running it on? Are you sure that API-level 8 is <= the API-level on the device?

Comment: Its LG optimus - black. How can I get the configuration of the device. I am sorry but I dont know if it is compatible with the API level 8.

Comment: Your device should be compatible, as it's currently running Android 2.2 (Froyo), a.k.a API-level 8.

Comment: Yeah. Thats what i thought. Any ideas why its not running?

Comment: By the way, I think the -1 is unwarranted. I tried to get the info on google but was not able to. And my omission on the word emulator was totally unintentional. I am genuinely confused and looking for help. After all, this site is for helping, right? Not bullying, I hope,

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to remove it upon you updating your post - now it's easier for us to grasp the situation. :-)

On another note, could you provide us with a sample of your app, to see if we're able to run it?

Comment: Its not public yet. If you want the code I can put it up. Do you want to take a look at the code?